# getting check box value

Tags: jquery

I want to get the value of the check box in the result variable. But I get the value as 'undefined' in the alert box. What is my mistake?

```
var result = "";
$("#required").change(function (){
        result= $(".mycheckbox:checked").val();
        alert(result);
        });


<div class=".mycheckbox">
<input id="required" type="checkbox" title="Required" name="required" value="required">
<label for="required">Required</label> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better to use click event instead of change, as change event works differently depending on browser e.g. [*IE only fires the change event when the checkbox loses focus*](http://krijnhoetmer.nl/stuff/javascript/checkbox-onchange/).

```
$(function() {
    $("#required").click(function (){ 
        var result= $(this).attr('checked');  
        alert(result);                
    });   
});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/eweye)

**Edit:**

I think I may have misunderstood your question. If you only want to display an alert with the checkbox value when the checkbox is checked then something like the following will work

```
$(function() {
    $("#required").click(function (){ 
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) { 
            var result = $(this).val();  
            alert(result);  
        }              
    }); 
});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/aqene)

Answer (score 4):

In you code

```
result= $(".mycheckbox:checked").val();
```

I think it should be

```
result= $("#required").val();
```

Answer (score 2):

$(".mycheckbox:checked") is not correct, it should be:

```
$(".mycheckbox :checked")
```

(note the space)

Your div declaration is also not correct. You shouldn't add the dot in the class name:

```
<div class="mycheckbox">
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
var result = ($("#required").is(':checked')) ? $("#required").val() : false;
```